# How to run client server communication between two different computers using tcp/ip?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

How to establish a client-server communication between two different systems using tcp/ip? I have done the code for server and client, but when i run the code, there is no error and moreover i am not able to see the file. I am attaching the code for further reference.

Server code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h> 
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<setjmp.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<assert.h>

//using namespace std;

long long int  send_audio(long long int socket)

{

    FILE *audio;
    long long int size, read_size, stat, packet_index;
    char send_buffer[1024000], read_buffer[1024000];
    packet_index = 1;

    audio = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/ROBO.mp3", "r");

    printf("Getting audio Size\n");

    if(audio == NULL)

    {

        printf("Error Opening audio File");
    }

    fseek(audio, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(audio);
    fseek(audio, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Total audio size: %lli \n", size);

    //Send audio Size

    printf("Sending audio Size\n");
    write(socket, (void *)&size, sizeof(int));

    //Send audio as Byte Array

    printf("Sending audio as Byte Array\n");

    do
    {

        //Read while we get errors that are due to signals.

        stat = read(socket, &read_buffer, 255);
        printf("Bytes read: %lli \n", stat);

    }

    while(stat < 0);

    printf("Received data in socket\n");
    printf("Socket data: %s\n", read_buffer);

    while(!feof(audio))

    {

        //while(packet_index = 1){
        //Read from the file into our send buffer

        read_size = fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer) - 1, audio);

        //Send data through our socket 

        do

        {

            stat = write(socket, send_buffer, read_size);

        }

        while(stat < 0);

        printf("Packet Number: %lli \n", packet_index);
        printf("Packet Size Sent: %lli \n", read_size);
        printf(" \n");
        printf(" \n");


        packet_index++;

        //Zero out our send buffer

        bzero(send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));

    }

}

long long int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    long long int socket_desc, new_socket, c, read_size, buffer = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char *readin;

    //Create socket

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_desc == -1)

    {

        printf("Could not create socket");

    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(6888);

    //Bind

    if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)

    {

        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;

    }

    puts("Bind completed");

    //Listen

    listen(socket_desc, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&c)))

    {

        puts("Connection accepted");

    }

    fflush(stdout);

    if(new_socket < 0)

    {

        perror("Accept Failed");
        return 1;

    }

    send_audio(new_socket);

    close(socket_desc);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Client code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>    
#include<unistd.h>

//using namespace std;

//This function is to be used once we have confirmed that an audio is to be sent //It should read and output an audio file

long long int receive_audio(long long int socket)

{

    long long int buffersize = 0, recv_size = 0, size = 0, read_size, write_size;

    char audioarray[1024000], verify = '1', errno;

    FILE *audio;

    //Find the size of the audio

    read(socket, &size, sizeof(int));

    //Send our verification signal

    write(socket, &verify, sizeof(char));

    //Make sure that the size is bigger than 0

    if(size <= 0)

    {

        printf("Error has occurred. Size less than or equal to 0 \n");      return -1;

    }

    audio = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/received.mp3", "w");

    if(audio == NULL)

    {

        printf("Error has occurred. audio file could not be opened \n");        return -1;

    }

    //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

    while(recv_size < size)

    {

        ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);

        //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket    

        if(buffersize > 0)

        {

            if(read_size = read(socket, audioarray, buffersize) < 0){
                printf("%s", strerror(errno));

            }

            //Write the currently read data into our audio file

            write_size = fwrite(audioarray, 1, (buffersize), audio);

            /* if(write_size != buffersize)

             {

             printf("write and buffer sizes are wrong \n");

             }

             if(read_size != write_size)

             {

             printf("error in read write \n");

             }  */

            //Increment the total number of bytes read

            recv_size += read_size;

            //Send our handshake verification info

            write(socket, &verify, sizeof(char));

        }   }

    fclose(audio);  printf("audio successfully Received! \n");  return 1; }

long long int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long long int socket_desc;  struct sockaddr_in server;  char *parray, errno;


    //Create socket

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(socket_desc == -1)

    {

        printf("Could not create socket \n");

    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));     server.sin_addr.s_addr = ("10.170.0.40");;  server.sin_family = AF_INET;    server.sin_port = htons(6888);

    //Connect to remote server

    if(connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)

    {


        //   printf(strerror(errno));

        close(socket_desc);

        printf("Connect Error \n");

        return -1;  }

    puts("Connected \n");

    receive_audio(socket_desc);

    close(socket_desc);

    return 0; }
```

Comment: You're printing out a lot of info. So what do you see ? What happens ?

Comment: Please fix your formatting issue, iit's very hard to read the code

Comment: `long long int main`???

Comment: `while (stat < 0);` -->> `while (stat > 0);` (plus a lot of other errors)

Comment: `long long int main` <-- in case main will be longer than 25 lines.

Comment: What is the data type that has to be given, instead of long long int main?

Comment: When i send an audio file from my computer to my friends system the connection is established, but i am not able to see the data in the given path. But the same code is working in localhost.

Comment: None of your read() or write() calls check their return values.  You need to do that so that you'll know if/when the calls fail, but just as importantly, you need to do that so that you'll know how many bytes of data were actually sent or received.  If you don't keep track of how many bytes were actually sent or received (which can and often will be fewer than the number of bytes you asked the call to send/receive) then your program will not be able to transfer the data reliably, because it won't know which bytes to send/receive next.

Answer (score 0):

`while (stat < 0);` → `while (stat > 0);` – joop